# Baking with unhulled sesame seeds versus hulled

Tags: baking, bread, seeds

I'm baking a sesame seed bread recipe from the Tartine Bread book and it calls for toasting the hulled seeds. Penzey only had hulled so, not having written it down, I figured that was what I was supposed to get.

Rather than worrying too much about it, should I just put the seeds into the dough raw, rather than toasting, or should I still toast them? What is any significant taste difference will there be? Why did he use unhulled instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dry roast the seeds before putting them in bread dough. It will have a really strong flavour. He used the unhulled seeds for the mild flavour. You can either use hulled or unhealed. I believe that you have washed the sesame seeds, dried them, dry roasted them and then ........ WHOOP in the dough. That will of course taste great....

Comment: In fact, that's what I did. I roasted them the same way as in the book directions but for less time; 15 minutes versus 30 but I only made half the recipe and was worried about burning them. The flavor was strong but perfect for the loaf as it was delicious and now one of my favorite breads.

Comment: Yes @Rob because the time left would be cooked within the dough so no worries.